# Как узнать, есть ли элементы позади данного элемента? | JS

Tags: javascript, css

У меня есть элемент Event[div]. Он absolute. Может быть так, что такой же элемент находится позади него или над ним, другими словами, он его касается. Как мне в таком случае изменять элемент? Пробовал использовать document.elementsFromPoint(coords.x, coords.y), но только я начинаю изменять элементы, как все перестает работать правильно.

Сейчас так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно стать так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А пример есть? Почему перестает работать `elementsFromPoint()` ?

Comment: Пробовали, к примеру, MutationObserver проверять elementsFromPoint() для элемента который мутировал? 
Есть много примеров hittest-ов, может что то от них взять? [hittest1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979718/i-need-help-making-a-hittest-in-javascript), [hittest2](http://jsfiddle.net/soulwire/u5WwX/)